# JPA Query annotation and joining table

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a sql query like this

```
Select * from DB1.Table1 a left join DB2.Table2 b on a.dCode = b.dCode where bID = 123;
```

How can I create jpa code for the above query? what would be the params of JpaRepository

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<???, ???> {

    @Query("???")
    ??? myTestQueryCOde(Integer bID);
}
```

What would be at `???`

Comment: Where does the `JpaRepository` class come from?

Comment: @Bhesh JpaRespository is part of Spring JPA Data.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if Spring JPA Data support cross DB queries, but have a look at [Cross database joins in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855872/cross-database-joins-in-jpa)